# Multiple logins in meteor

Tags: meteor

In my application I want users github and linkedin account data

My app has it's own user base with `accounts-password`

now I want to connect the github and linkedin accounts to the current user

Is there a way to do this? something like

If I take the login details in client side and if I perform

```
loginWithService()
```

in server side, Is it going to work??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to merge accounts from login with GitHub and LinkedIn, see this package: https://atmospherejs.com/bozhao/link-accounts

Comment: seems like linkedIn is not supporting yet, Anyway thanks for the response